# Coldfusion development server is slower than production

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server-2008, performance

We've built a development server to test our web applications before moving them to deployment.

This is the configuration of the development server :

> Win Server 2k8 - 32bit - Web edition
>  
>   Coldfusion 9 Entreprise
>   MySQL 5
>  
>   IIS 6

This configuration is the replica of the production environment.
Unfortunately, we are faced with slow execution times.
Example: the execution time of an application, already launched on a production server, takes an average 45-60ms versus 500-600ms on development.
And when we must restart the application, which happens quite often in development, we lose a lot of time... 6500-7000ms :( (vs 1200ms)

I have tried the same application on my local server (my computer), and the response time is equivalent to the production server.

This is the JVM config of the development server:

> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
>   -server -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../
>   -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib

The source files are hosted on a NAS; we had to create a user on the NAS, exactly the same as the admin user of the server. And we had to configure Coldfusion and IIS application pools to run as the created user to address access rights. But I don't think this is the problem because I did some tests, putting the files on a disk local to server, and the execution time remains the same.

I don't know where to look...

** The server monitor is shut down **

Someone would have any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the many possible reasons:

- Is the development server of equivalent power?
- Have you turned off debugging?
- Have you turned on trusted cache?
- Do both machines have the same setting for `Disable CFC Type Check`?
- Do you have the same jvm minimum and maximum heap size settings on both machines? e.g. `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`
- Do you have any server monitoring options turned on locally, but not on the live server?
- Does your app connect to a database server that is local to the production server, but remote to the dev server?

Comment: The development server has:
- Pentium DualCore CPU @ 3.00Ghz
- 4 GB Ram
- 32 bit
Not really bad...

Comment: Line debugger turned off
Trusted cache turned on (the production sever is off)
Disable CFC Type Check : checked (the production is not checked)

The response is now a little more powerful.

Comment: Both JVM config are the same
Server monitoring turned off everywhere

Comment: One more possibility: does your app connect to a database server that is local to the production server, but remote to the dev server?

Comment: No, both are connected to a local database server. A MySQL 5.
Turning off the debugger has accelerated the generation of the page but on my local server, it is activated and it poses no problem.

Comment: Trusted cache should be *on* for production and *off* for dev.  It will be a little slower on dev, but otherwise you'll have to clear the cache everytime you change a template which is less then ideal.  +1 to Ken's other suggestions and Mark Mandel's answer.

Comment: @Todd, I agree. Trusted cache should be off for dev; I'm just suggesting he try turning it on to see if it helps explain the performance deficit. I'd also have "disable CFC type check" *on* for production and *off* for dev (meaning, no type checking on production -- gotta hate double-negative configuration options). Type checking happens at run-time, and can noticeably affect performance.

Comment: ugh...right.  no type checking on production is what i meant.

Comment: Foiled by the double-negative. I love it when you have to check a checkbox to "turn on the off switch". Good feature, bad control panel.

Comment: I'm pulling my hair! An application restart take 80.000 ms !! I had to increase the request timeout...
If I put the extactly same application on the production server, the restart take 1200ms !

Comment: When I link at the resource monitor of the dev server, I can see, when I call a coldfusion resquest, that the CPU don't jump realy. The graph remains in the bottom... Is Coldfusion restricted ?

Comment: Are both machines running the same version of the JVM?

Comment: Yes. There are both 1.6.0_14.

Comment: Perhaps it's a network port contention issue: http://www.ghidinelli.com/2011/01/11/cold-fusion-slow-start-messagebrokerservlet

Comment: Thanks but this post talk about slow startup of coldfusion and not slow request. Thank anyway

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried to build a new test/development server? On the rare occasion where things weren't quite right (ex: errors, slow response, connectivity issues), a rebuild works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Answer seems to be pretty usual: try [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/fr/) to find out the bottleneck. It is really hard to "guess" the reasons with this information...

Comment: I'll test it. Do you need more information ? I have to give more details but tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you turned off 'Report Execution Times'?

That can cause a HUGE slowdown in CFC heavy applications (and pretty much any complex application)

Comment: 'Report Execution Times' turned off. Execution time not changed :s :s :s

Answer (score 1):

LarZuK, you say "the server monitor is shutdown": Do you mean the CF Enterprise Server Monitor (available in the free Developer edition, too)? If so, let's make sure you mean what it seems you're saying: are you saying "the server monitor interface has been closed?" That doesn't mean anything, to be honest.

If you enable any of the "start" features, especially "start memory tracking", then it does NOT matter if the monitor interface is OPEN. You have caused CF to start doing that monitoring, whether you open the interface or not.

I suspect that could be your problem. Open the monitor and click "stop memory tracking" if it's on (and "stop profiling", too, if you have lots of queries, as that tracks them). "Start Monitoring" is the least burdensome. Let us know how that turns out.

Like others have said, there could be dozens of other explanations, and it's hard to guess and go through all of them without more info. A tool like FusionReactor or the CF Server Monitor can give more details, but it can be tricky to know how best to interpret what they tell you. I try to help through various resources like my own site (carehart.org, including my blog, articles, and presentations) and a new cf911.com site I'm building out. I also offer consulting to help people, on-demand, and short-term, but I realize you may not seek such help for a problem only with your development server.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Hi Charlie,
The ** The server monitor is shut down ** was picture of the task manager of windows. It was hosted by imageshack :s No I know the issue s you can have when the CF monitor stay open. In fact the problem was the disk access and store the execution in NAS through the lan was an good idea ;)